# Set class attribute to an inherited class

Tags: python, object

I have a base class named `foo`. This class gets inherited by another class named `boo`. I would like to have all methods within the boo object to go into `foo` such that I can call `boo` objects like `foo.boo.example_attribute()`

```
class foo:
    # this class puts things into the env object for use in other files

class boo(foo):
    example_attribute = "Blah Blah"
```

My goal would be to have `print(foo.boo.example_attribute)` output "Blah Blah"

I've tried explicitly setting everything with boo to be defined as foo.boo.example_attribute but I realized this isn't scalable and seems pretty sloppy.

Comment: `foo.boo = boo` would give you that outcome.  But it seems that you have the inheritance going the wrong way: if `foo` inherited from `boo` instead of vice versa, you could just say `print(foo.example_attribute)`.